# Setting up a 2nd tablet to look like the 1st before resetting (and returning) the 1st?

Tags: backup, factory-reset, restore

I bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 and browsed the net and installed some apps on it - fortunately not many as it was basically getting a "test drive" and I had a feeling it wasn't being kept. I was right, I will be returning it to the shop and I'll obviously do a factory reset before doing so. What I'd like to know is whether it's possible to restore/copy the data to a second device so that I've got my apps/browsing history/bookmarks etc etc on the second device rather than having to reinstall everything on the new Tab 4. The movies/music/pictures are all on an SD card which will hopefully help, it's the apps that I'm curious about, especially since some of the games keep track of how far you've progressed and I wouldn't want to start from scratch!

Looking forward to getting some ideas from you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look closely, you can find the solution for partial backup [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices).